# API call doesn't result in image loading

Tags: java, android

I was trying to build a memesharing app with an meme Api call but when i launched the app on the emulator, the meme doesn't seem to load. I cant really understand where i'm going wrong. It would be really helpful if you could point out my mistake.

```
   private void loadMeme()
{

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url ="https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme";

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
   JsonObjectRequest JsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    ImageView memeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.memeImageView);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into(memeImageView);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
```

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
}

Comment: You have a response but you don't seem to be using that as far as I can see. You are making Glide load the API endpoint for you which is not an image providing url

Answer (score 1):

> You forgot fetch the image url from your API and also forgot to add request to the request queue in Volley. Add this code to your project it will work

```
private void loadMeme() {
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        JsonObjectRequest JsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            String imageUrl = response.getString("url");
                            ImageView memeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.memeImageView);
                            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(imageUrl).into(memeImageView);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        queue.add(JsonObjectRequest);
    }
```